# How would I convert iso dateformat to timestamp using firebase admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

How would I convert the following dateformat `2020-09-18T18:36:15.000Z` to Timestamp using the firebase-admin npm package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `fromDate` function like this:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const str = "2020-09-18T18:36:15.000Z";
const timestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(str))
```

Check the documentation for further readings [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#static-fromdate).

Comment: How would I convert iso date format to UCT?

Comment: I am getting a "Error: Value for argument "seconds" is not a valid integer" error

Comment: which version of `firebase-admin` do you run? I tested it on `10.1.0` with my answer and it works just fine.

Comment: updated my answer with the `import` and the missing Z in the iso timestamp.

Comment: Updated my firebase-admin version and it worked now, thank you